# Am I interpreting the output of my logistic regression probabilities correctly?

Tags: r, regression, probability, logistic, logit

I have conducted a logistic regression in R looking at if fish feed in the presence of a decoy predator. Here is a shortened sample:

```
Condition      Feed
No Decoy        Y
No Decoy        Y
No Decoy        Y
No Decoy        Y
No Decoy        N
No Decoy        N
No Decoy        N
Decoy           Y
Decoy           Y
Decoy           Y
Decoy           N
Decoy           N
Decoy           N
Decoy           N
```

N.B This data has 206 rows with no decoy/decoy conditions split 100:106.

I have run the following code in R to conduct the model and convert normal probability from the logits:

```
##Logistic1$Feed = Feeding Data, Logistic1$Condition = Decoy Data##

model1 <- glm(Logistic1$Feed ~ Logistic1$Condition, 
family=binomial(link='logit'))
summary(model1)   

logit2prob <- function(logit){
  odds <- exp(logit)
  prob <- odds / (1 + odds)
  return(prob)
}

coef(model1)
test<-logit2prob(coef(model1))
test
(intercept <- coef(model1)[1])
(Value <- coef(model1)[2])
(Feedprob<-intercept+2*Value)
logit2prob(Value)
exp(coef(model1))

newdata <- data.frame(Condition=1, Condition=2)
predict(model1, newdata, type="response")
```

The output of this gives me 216 values. Rows 0-100 show: 0.17821782 and rows 101-206 show: 0.06666667

From reading guides online, the final command results in a single value which is the probability. I'm assuming something to do with my data and coding means this is showing the probabilities that feeding occurs in the no decoy (18%) and decoy conditions (7%) but it's just showing it for every value?

Comment: Look carefully at the values you've assigned to `newdata`.  (Try printing out `newdata`.)   Does it look right?  If `predict` doesn't get meaningful `newdata`, depending upon the specific `predict.x` function it might revert to the default, which is to generate predictions for every row in the original data frame.

Comment: You are correct. After looking more carefully I noticed a warning when running the predict function: 
"Warning message: 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 110 rows"
As you say it must just be reverting to default due to the mismatch.

Would you be able to confirm if I am reading the output correctly and the probability is the percentage chance of my dependant occurring? If so, it doesn't matter if it is displaying differently as I will have the information I need. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you're correct, the probabilities are as you suspect.  If you make your `newdata = data.frame(Condition=c('Decoy', 'No Decoy'))`, that should work too.